# variable error on logistic regression/ proc catmod- Building predictive model

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, predictive-models, sas

I am using logistic regression to fit a model with categorical/multinomial varaibles.
data-description: There are over 300 variables as independent variables, sample size is 5000 which is divided into 80/20 for train/validation.

I am getting the following error on 2 different procedures that I have tried upon,
here is the code: proc logistic data=a outest=b covout;
                           model dependent= list of independent;
                                    /selection=stepwise
                                     slenrty=0.70 slstay=0.75 details lackfit;
                  run;

I know step-wise is not the best approach but my question pertains to this:

1. error: "variable x should either be numeric or in classes list"
   So I formatted the variable into numeric, but it still is giving me the same error?
   I cant figure out what to do?
2. I applied proc catmod on the same exact data/variable to fit the multinomial logistic model and it gives me this error: "variable x in list does not match type prescribed for this list". The error comes for the same set of variables. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Also, HOW DO i tell sas to treat all of these variables as categorical? or is it just a programming error? I cant understand why am I getting this error?
Any help would be much appreciated; I am stuck at this point and my experience level on statistics/modeling is of a beginner!

Comment: Don't you need a CLASS statement? `CLASS x;` Read [the manual](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#logistic_toc.htm).

Comment: CLASS statement is optional, I think..

Comment: Class statement is used to tell SAS that the variable is categorical with multiple levels. If the variable is character it definitely needs to be in the class statement. If it is numeric with 0/1 then its fine to not include it in the class statement.

Comment: Reese..Ok say I followed your advice. I placed all the character variables in class statement and all the observations (both character and numeric) into the model statement. Now it is returning with an error: "There are no valid observations" ...what did i do wrong now?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787219/sas-no-valid-observations-are-found-error-simple-regression). BTW if there isn't going to be any statistical aspect to your question it'd be better on Stack Overflow or the SAS support [forum](https://communities.sas.com/community/support-communities).